# rsa encryption with javascrypt decrypt in python

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, velo

I'm trying to encrypt using Wix-Velo in javascript using hybrid-crypto-js,
and decrypt using python using PKCS1_v1_5 and I'm getting incorrect length error.

This is my code in Javascript:

```javascrpit
    var Crypt = require('hybrid-crypto-js').Crypt;
    var crypt = new Crypt();

    var publicKey = "publicKey";

    var privateKey = "privateKey";

    var message = 'Hello world!';
    
    // Encryption with one public RSA key
    var encrypted = crypt.encrypt(publicKey, message);
```

In python:

```python
def decrypt_rsa(data: bytes, key: str = rsa_key) -> str:
    key = key.replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "").replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----",
                                                                     "").replace("\n", "")
    key = b64decode(key)
    key = RSA.importKey(key)

    cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
    return cipher.decrypt(data, "Error while decrypting".encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: _hybrid-crypto-js_ applies hybrid encryption, i.e. encrypts the message with AES/CBC and the AES key with RSA/OAEP. The ciphertext contains, among other things, the encrypted AES key, the encrypted message, and the IV. Accordingly, in the Python code, the AES key must be decrypted first, and then the message with AES using key and IV. Currently, only RSA decryption is performed (it is unclear what data is decrypted), where the padding (PKCS#1 v1.5) is wrong. The AES part is missing. Btw, _PyCryptodome_ also accepts PEM-encoded keys.

Comment: Hi. thank you for your answer. i'm a little bit confused about the python side. can you please share a code for this problem? also, I've fixed the input of the data in the javascript side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to explain this is with an example. The following key pair is used for the example:

```js
var publicKey = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCfm2uMTvb+gqXRFxWHnfCKcHfH
v7aMN6oiEqTJj0BixtTYBXH89N+xuYgoIBnfMXPXPIg/UNWEOZtAETsOVvya+YBo
ZZTquYJ2I0PaxtpUKkpCiEQ/bTCQIDAeUwHr0l4vUn/fmslD0rZ3+jo4Dsl8nX0O
pwZQ2grQaXLb347RQwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;

var privateKey = `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`
```

For reasons of space, a 1024 bits key is used. Note, however, that for security reasons RSA keys with a size of at least 2048 bits must be used in practice today.

One possible output of the posted JavaScript code using this key pair is:

```js
{
    "v":"hybrid-crypto-js_0.2.4",
    "iv":"qAoNKj6kM0whA07xOdeiPVLF2ntPjKXWXdmy0IhJmF0=",
    "keys":{"e7:de:4a:da:6b:c8:ed:3a:bd:70:4d:87:23:99:9a:23:2a:ad:17:f8":"NvpGk/XyB+m+gC/d/Bzp16xXjxNKIJq4SAsz4y11OWQJa9K42jzjona18CJnsP6OZh/wmF709KgX7ZGYnqVGswQ0Q2PpLpG39t7ipj/N6taqkAy9Mydstt4Agdu5dQ8wLCSBpU3NNrgp6T06nI0Y1ISX2H45kgI47PeQnjYB4gQ="},
    "cipher":"JZIHkdUd1NuKt2aj2OMdLQ=="
}
```

The first element is the version, the second the IV, the third the AES key encrypted with RSA/OAEP and the fourth the ciphertext encrypted with AES-256/CBC, s. [Hybrid Crypto JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hybrid-crypto-js#encryption).

To decrypt the key, the posted Python/PyCryptodome code can be used, changing the padding from PKCS#1 v1.5 to OAEP and using the above RSA key and ciphertext:

```python
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import base64

privateKey = """-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    MIICXQIBAAKBgQCfm2uMTvb+gqXRFxWHnfCKcHfHv7aMN6oiEqTJj0BixtTYBXH8
    9N+xuYgoIBnfMXPXPIg/UNWEOZtAETsOVvya+YBoZZTquYJ2I0PaxtpUKkpCiEQ/
    bTCQIDAeUwHr0l4vUn/fmslD0rZ3+jo4Dsl8nX0OpwZQ2grQaXLb347RQwIDAQAB
    AoGBAJHi3s/10X/a7TOMFQrLy3TOzj1PN808iA7y2Zq+jIx8z0nQ2FrtfJYXTqPW
    i69dpVOkKakt+qwMd6J83W0DB4oyRAQriBPI2BNuTQguzeBmvC3bkrAhbfRU313G
    fdlUFprS+LTvb0+KCbAMM8/I0pwQMZm0K1lWSp7ILkW2/ICJAkEAz22+7TN9bx44
    0VYm2HunmbuDA5APwDmBl9VmDCCcB9/mHPbHXIuMHAWxaZma+euq2uLeCdCzVdwE
    nk3bSNhLFwJBAMT7BeJLuob6iA4BsUyfjxQjdjTMaP4J6JWCfcFQvd2hcwcikm/W
    0qcbrKv8yCgMg1C0U9iwV3g+G6RRobbYVrUCQQDLNN1FLRsl33qUAY0+qS0Q2vTH
    abs0emGtqB43pT6WLE8Xct7tl7vju+QI6rU7Pxd7JaOWBAGcDFXt66H2ZAZzAkA4
    sHmgB+VVpVJ0nX4WLDF0PURuq4ln2xgptxVUBlWuLCG7ovJ751pWp3tJQAWmqPs9
    xbf/u7hgrZcs8iVVRuulAkBAoBFO1gN1utEtr97z3lHSHjL150Tqu/w0qXI4lbuH
    CaAiwWj6QRUnVkYlVK56Nzl/S3MLc6OT9GN9X/B+1Ebl
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"""

ciphertext = base64.b64decode("NvpGk/XyB+m+gC/d/Bzp16xXjxNKIJq4SAsz4y11OWQJa9K42jzjona18CJnsP6OZh/wmF709KgX7ZGYnqVGswQ0Q2PpLpG39t7ipj/N6taqkAy9Mydstt4Agdu5dQ8wLCSBpU3NNrgp6T06nI0Y1ISX2H45kgI47PeQnjYB4gQ=")
key = RSA.importKey(privateKey)
cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)
message = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)

print(message.hex()) # 8ec759594b7cc96c44d624f5a58bf736a9f761f3191de2fd0ff1e5c2bb3a8868
```

Now the actual ciphertext can be decrypted:

```python
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad
from base64 import b64decode

iv = b64decode("qAoNKj6kM0whA07xOdeiPVLF2ntPjKXWXdmy0IhJmF0=")[:AES.block_size]
key = bytes.fromhex("8ec759594b7cc96c44d624f5a58bf736a9f761f3191de2fd0ff1e5c2bb3a8868")
ciphertext = b64decode("JZIHkdUd1NuKt2aj2OMdLQ==")
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
decrypted = unpad(cipher.decrypt(ciphertext), AES.block_size)
print(str(len(decrypted)) + " - " + decrypted.decode('utf-8')) # 12 - Hello world!
```

Note that the IV has a length of 32 bytes, of which only the first 16 bytes (corresponding to the AES block size) are used for AES.

For completeness: The fingerprint `e7:de...17:f8` used in the ciphertext of the JavaScript code is the SHA1 hash of the public key in PKCS#1 format, DER encoded.